# Quiz in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I'm not sure on how to make the options in my quiz change from question 1 to 2 without having to open a new window. I need that after the user clicks submit, a new window would open that says correct if the answer is correct (ans 1) with an OK button. Then after the user clicks ok, the previous question window would change into a new question. Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk
def open_easyquiz():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("6 Questions")
    window.geometry("500x150")
    score = 0
    labelcorrect = tk.Label(window, text="Correct! +1")
    answers = ["Livro", "1"]
    def inst():
        t = tk.Label(window, text="All you need to do is just answer each question with either a '1, 2, 3' or the actual word. You will see a word in English at the top and you have to answer with the most similar word in Portuguese.")
        t.pack()

    def start():

        def submit():
            if ans == answers[0] or answers[1]:


                rootc = tk.Tk()
                rootc.title = "Correct!"
                ok = tk.Button(rootc, text="OK", command = question2 and rootc.destroy)
                print("correct")
                labelcorrect.pack(rootc)


            #or do whatever you like with this

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Question")
        q = tk.Label(root, text="Book")
        q.pack()
        a = tk.Label(root, text="1.) Livro")
        a.pack()
        b = tk.Label(root, text="2.) Laranja")
        b.pack()
        c = tk.Label(root, text="3.) Borboleta")
        c.pack()
        ans = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
        ans.pack()
        #here is the button I want to verify the answer
        sub = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit)
        sub.pack()


    greet = tk.Label(window, text="Welcome to the EASY Question Quiz.")
    greet.pack()
    startButton = tk.Button(window, command=start, text="Start")
    startButton.pack()
    instr = tk.Button(window, text="Instructions", command=inst)
    instr.pack()
    end = tk.Button(window, text="Exit", command=window.destroy)
    end.pack()

    window.mainloop()
open_easyquiz()
```

Comment: Welcome to [so].Please check [ask] and make your question a [mcve] .

Answer (score 0):

You should try using different pages for different questions:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is question 1")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class Page2(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is question 2")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class Page3(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is question 3")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        p3 = Page3(self)

        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p3.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 1", command=p1.lift)
        b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 2", command=p2.lift)
        b3 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 3", command=p3.lift)

        b1.pack(side="left")
        b2.pack(side="left")
        b3.pack(side="left")

        p1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("400x400")
    root.mainloop()
```

You can do this in many ways. You can put a button on each page to check for the answer given  through an entry and then, print correct or wrong. This way you can have as many questions as you want, and it gives you flexibility.

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `root.destroy()` by destroying the question window and opening a new one.